# Implementin SRWebSocketDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, socketrocket

I am implementing:

```
@protocol SRWebSocketDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message;

@optional

- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket;
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didCloseWithCode:(NSInteger)code reason:(NSString *)reason wasClean:(BOOL)wasClean;
```

in Swift. All functions I can implement ok and works, but `didCloseWithCode` I just can't make it to work.

I am having trouble implementing

```
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didCloseWithCode:(NSInteger)code reason:(NSString *)reason wasClean:(BOOL)wasClean;
```

in Swift.

I am trying:

```
func webSocket(webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didCloseWithCode code: NSInteger!, reason: NSString!, wasClean: Bool!) {
    println("websocket closed: \(reason)")
    self.connect(5.0)
}
```

with no luck.

Comment: I believe swift converts NSString to String - try changing that?
Edit: Same with NSInteger. See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2344214&seqNum=8

Comment: I have already tried that with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
func webSocketDidOpen(webSocket: SRWebSocket!) {
    DDLogInfo("socket opened");
}

func webSocket(webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didCloseWithCode code: Int, reason: String!, wasClean: Bool) {
    DDLogError("code: \(code) reason:\(reason) ");
}

func webSocket(webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    DDLogError("error: \(error)");
}

func webSocket(webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didReceiveMessage message: AnyObject!) {
}
```